# how to store hour and minute in a "Time" object

Tags: android, time, timepicker

I'm using android studio, I have a timepicker that the user will choose (hour and minute) I should store this information of time in a (time) object to pass it to the database
how can I store the hour and minute in a time object?
I hope it's clear

hourOfDay// will store the hour for what user choose ..
minute //will store the minute for what user choose

```
pickerTime = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.pickertime);
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

        pickerTime.setHour(now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        pickerTime.setMinute(now.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

        pickerTime.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "onTimeChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                info.setText(
                        "Hour of Day: " + hourOfDay + "\n" +
                                "Minute: " + minute);
            }});
```

Comment: why not storing directly in database instead of using an extra object?

Comment: I should use this time for notifications in the phone, if I didn't put the hour&minute in an object how can I store them? separated?

Comment: There is a Java Date object...

Comment: I'm using android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need set it in the formal time in Database `HH:MM`

```
public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

         // date is final String variable               
           date = String.valueOf(hourOfDay).toString() + ":" + String.valueOf(minute).toString();
        }
```

this is get your time in one string `HH:MM` think it you need

Comment: Incompatible types < this error when I use your code :(

Comment: what is the type of "date" ? is it Time?

Comment: see my comment line : `date is final String variable `

Comment: and I just learn something new :) , when I pass time object to the database its ok to pass it as string ! I was in a pig miss for this little thing :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
    pickerTime = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.pickertime);
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    pickerTime.setHour(now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    pickerTime.setMinute(now.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

    pickerTime.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "onTimeChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

            Date date = now.getTime();

            info.setText("Hour of Day: " + hourOfDay + "\n" +
                            "Minute: " + minute);
        }});
```

Comment: pickerTime  will be an object of type TimePicker ,, but in my database I have it in Time type ,, that my problem

Comment: press alt + enter over Date you will get Options to import date then select java.util date.

Comment: Add `import java.util.Date;` to imports